# Transition a Poco StreamSocket to a SecureStreamSocket

Tags: c++, ssl, poco-libraries, ftps

I'm modifying an application embedded FTP server I have previously written for a customer to support FTPS and while I have implicit mode working by passing a SecureServerSocket to the TCPSocketServer, I want to support Explicit mode where the connection start as a regular socket connection, and when receiving a AUTH TLS, switch the StreamSocket to a SecureStreamSocket and send a server hanshake.

I have attempted to use the attach method, but it seem to send a client hand shake rather than server one.
So then I tried to create a server context when creating the SecureStreamSocket, but get "GnuTLS error -19: An unexpected TLS handshake packet was received" when trying to connect from filezilla.

```
const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr ctx = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::SERVER_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH"); 
SecureStreamSocket *test = new SecureStreamSocket(ctx);
test->attach(socket());
```

Have anyone successfully transition a already established POCO TCPServer connection to Secure connection and if so, how did you do it - any hints would be helpfull.

Comment: `SecureStreamSocket` has some static functions to attach a `StreamSocket` to a `SecureStreamSocket`.  Like `static SecureStreamSocket attach(const StreamSocket& streamSocket,...`.  But I think you want to use it like `SecureStreamSocket test = SecureStreamSocket::attach(yourSocket...`

Comment: thank for pointing this out, but the result is the same: GnuTLS error -19: An unexpected TLS handshake packet was received.

Comment: After assigning a error handler to Poco, it logs the following error at the time of the attach:  error:141A10F4:SSL routines:ossl_statem_client_read_transition:unexpected message

Comment: Seems like an issue with the protocol switching sequence?

Comment: Is your POCO FTP server code available somewhere? needing one. thanks

Comment: The server was written for a client as work for hire and belongs to them, thus can't be shared. in addition, it's not a general purpose server, the files uploaded are not written out to a file system but internally processed.